# Plot 3D array with uneven lengths in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 1974x2x20 matrix. It is spectrogram data collected overtime that I am trying to 3D plot. Since it isn't uniform length waterfall() and surf() will not plot it. I have tried using mesh grid but no such luck.

```
data(1974,2,20) = rand();
```

I have tried to plot using

```
surf(data);
```

and

```
waterfall(data);
```

Since it is not of equal length they both error. I'm not sure how to continue or transform it into the appropriate array.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and didn't work. Also read how to create [*a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Okay I added some code to show what I have tried.

Comment: If you have a variable `A(x,y,z)=V` then you dont have 3D data, you have volumetric data. `surf` works for variables of type `A(x,y)=z`

Comment: @AnderBiguri The data I have is 1974 wavelengths each with a corresponding amplitude collected over time. I want to plot this 2d data over time so you can see all the data on one plot.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I'm trying to create something like this http://case.caltech.edu/tfr/wv5.png

Comment: @Tall_Programer that ddata is `A(x,y)=z`, so you  have extra data